# Moq does not recognize the Setup for a method that does not receive the object needed in the dependency

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am now using Moq. I have a case where I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I hope you can guide me.

the code and the testing are:

```js
public class MyLogic{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public MyLogic(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<Product> Create(Estimate estimate, Policy policy)
    {
        Product product = new Product(policy.Title, estimate.Id);
        return await _repository.Create(product);
    }
}

[Fact]
public Class MyLogicTest{
    Mock<IRepository> _repository = new DBRepository();
    MyLogic myLogic =  new MyLogic(_repository);

    Estimate _estimate = new Estimate(){
        Id = Guid.Parse("5aa4d4a1-23e4-495b-b990-08da0d38e5df")
    };

    Policy _policy = new Policy(){
        Title = "The Title"
    };

    public async Task CreateShouldBeDifferentFromNull(){
        Product product = new Product()
        {
            Title = "The Title",
            Id = Guid.Parse("5aa4d4a1-23e4-495b-b990-08da0d38e5df")               
        };

        _repository.Setup(g => g.Create(product)).ReturnsAsync(() => product);
        Product createdProduct = await myLogic.Create(_estimate, _policy);

        Assert.NotNull(createdProduct);
        Assert.Equal(product.Id, createdProduct.Id);

        _repository.Verify(g => g.Create(product));
    }
}
```

The Assert always fails because createdProduct is always null. And, I know I can change the class MyLogic to receive a Product instead of the two parameters. But what I want is to test the code as it is.

How can I make the mocked IRepository use the Product instance I declared in the test in order for the test to succeed?

Comment: I will be able to help you only when you provide an example that works. Where is _productRepository, productCommand declaration?

Comment: @BasilKosovan I just fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the `Create` method to return your wanted `Product` when it receives an instance of the type `Product` with some specific `Title` and some specific `Id`. Now you are setting up the `Create` method to return your wanted `Product` when it receives exactly that object you created. Which of course fails because that is completely another different object than the one created inside your `Create` method.
So change your setup line to:
`_productRepository.Setup(g => g.Create(It.Is<Product>(p => p.Id == product.Id && p.Title == product.Title)).ReturnsAsync(() => product);`
Alternatively you can override Equals method and == operator and your original code will work as well.

Comment: Thanks! that worked... however when running the line: _productRepository.Verify(g => g.Create(product)); I got  Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: g => g.Create(Product) do you know why?

Comment: For the same reason. The method was never called with that specific Product. It was called with another instance of Product with the same property values.